# Get hidden value from nearby input onclick of an image class

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have the following dynamic div in my Laravel blade, where the hidden input values will be myImg0, myImg1 etc.

```
<div id="img-container" class="img-container" >
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <img class="img-option "  id="myImg{{$i}}" src="{{ $qstImg}}" alt="" >
     <input type="hidden" value="myImg{{$i}}" class="imageIds">
  </div>
</div>
```

Onclick of image, I want to get the hidden value of the input box.

Js,

```
$('.img-container').on('click','.img-option',function(event){
var imageIds = $(this).parents().find('input.imageIds').val();
});
```

But on alert I am getting same value itself.

Comment: Are you expecting `imageIds` to be an array?

Comment: When I click on the image I need the value like myImg0, myImg1 etc.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just get the `id` attribute of the `img`, because it's exactly the same:

```
$('.img-container').on('click','.img-option', function() {
  var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log( imageId );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the right code for you.

```
$('.img-container').on('click','.img-option',function(event){
    var imageIds = $(this).parent().find('input.imageIds').val();
});
```

Should be parent instead of parents.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:

```
<div id="img-container" class="img-container" >
  <div class="imgWrap">
    <a onclick="funcGetID('{{"myImg".$i}}')"><img class="img-option "  id="myImg{{$i}}" src="{{ $qstImg}}" alt="" ></a>
     <input type="hidden" value="myImg{{$i}}" class="imageIds">
  </div>
</div>
```

//js code

```
<script>
  function funcGetID(x)
   {
     alert(x);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: i used <a></a>  tag and pass myimg to the function because the input field value and the value of the <a></a> tag will always be same